# Artifact is getting uploaded to wrong group in Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I am using [Gradle-Artifactory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) of Jenkins to upload my artifacts to Artifactory. After the successful build, the artifact is getting uploaded to wrong directory in Artifactory.

I need the artifact to upload at the path `libs-snapshot-local/com/myorg/usr/1.0/myfile-1.0.war` but it instead get loaded to `libs-snapshot-local/com.myorg.usr/1.0/myfile-1.0.war`

I have below settings in my `build.gradle` file

```
group = 'com.myorg.usr'
archivesBaseName = 'myfile'
version = '1.0'
```

Comment: Please add your `artifactory {}` block definition. Also do you use `maven` or `maven-plublish` plugin? In case of the later, please also add your `publications {}` block definition.

Comment: what is the need to add `artifactory{}` block? I am using the `Jenkins-Artifactory` plugin which uploads artifactory without the need to include that block. And I don't use `maven` or `maven-publish` plugin.

Comment: Ah, got it. Then a screen-shot of the relevant part of the job config will be handy.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/R6GbMqPr - here you go. I have pasted my build.gradle file

Comment: and here is the screen shot of configuration http://s10.postimg.org/3ohwogqux/artifactory_configuration.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the `Use Maven compatible patterns` checkbox.